# How to write to the VSTS log output?

Tags: logging, c#-4.0, azure-pipelines

I have a piece of C# run during my VSTS Release task and I want it to write to the log output so I can see what it is doing, as I would have it write to the console on my local machine.

How can I write to the VSTS log output?

I have tried:

```
Console.WriteLine();
Debug.WriteLine();
testContext.WriteLine(); // from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
```

Comment: Are you calling your c# through PowerShell?

Comment: No; The VSTS Test task is executing it.

Comment: I wrote my vsts task to call a powershell script to call  c# code and routed the console to write to output. If you want to try that I can find the code snippet

Comment: The test task needs to be used (AFAIK) so I can more easily collect the test report. I just need to know how xUnit et al are writing to the output. They do it so I must be able to.

Comment: @ryan-schlueter I would appreciate that snippet, please?

Comment: Yep for sure I will post 1st thing tomorrow morning when I get into work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$oldOut = [Console]::Out
$newOut = New-Object IO.StringWriter
$coverage = new-object SQLCover.CodeCoverage ($connectionString, $databaseName)
try
{
   [Console]::SetOut($newOut)
   $coverage.Cover("exec tSQLt.RunAll")
 }
 finally
 {
    [Console]::SetOut($oldOut)
 }
 $output = 'Console output from DLL call: ' + $newOut.ToString()
```